# extracting data from multiple tables in sql db

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, join

Hi i have a database which consists of 2 tables

userData table

```
userID  |  userPass | Firstname |  Surname | Status | IPAddress
--------------------------------------------------------------  
110110  |  123456   | James     |  Jackson | Online |  11.112.1
```

contacts table

```
    userID  |  contactID |
    --------------------- 
    110110  |  112114    |
    112112  |  110110    |
    110110  |  112444    |
```

The first table is the userdata table which I am using with my java application for login. I also have another table which stores the users contacts , I am trying to write a query to allow me to take the users contacts and display them by the first name, surname and ID in a JList, I am extremely puzzled any help would be appreciated. I had a look at inner joins but seem to be getting more stuck. how can I construct a query to get the data i need? I am also trying to make a separate query to display only the online users.

ok i have managed to use the following query:

```
SELECT userName
FROM userdata, contacts
WHERE userID = "110110" AND userData.userID = contacts.contactID
```

This is taking the userID "110110" from the contacts tables and the contactID's which correspond and returning the userName (from the userdata table)of the contacts. i have encountered a new problem where  userID 112112 added 110110 as a friend. because of this 112112 is in the userID column and 110110 is in the contactID column (contacts table). this shouldnt be a problem as it still shows they are contacts. however I have tried to modify my query to also give me the name for the userID 112112. can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Do you want to just show all the users?

Comment: You should read about `JOIN` SQL

Answer (score 1):

> name, surname and ID

Assuming by ID you mean contactID, otherwise additional join should be included to fetch data from Contacts.

```
select u.Firstname, u.Surname, uc.contactID from User u 
inner join UserContact uc on u.userID = uc.userID;
```

[More on joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the users -

```
select Firstname, Surname, u.contactID from userdata u inner join usercontacts uc 
on u.userID = uc.userID order by Firstname, Surname, u.userID
```

To get online users -

```
select Firstname, Surname, u.contactID from userdata u inner join usercontacts uc 
on u.userID = uc.userID where status = 'Online' order by Firstname, Surname, u.userID
```

Comment: the contact ID is essentially a userID , I think I have struxtured my db wrong

Comment: I have made some changes and updated my question slightly please take a look, thanks.